# problema de compatibilidad con input search button y search bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, programación-móvil

Tengo este boton que abre un top bar cuando la pantalla es menor que 1080px y cuando es mayor que 1080px abre una linea horizontal para hacer la busqueda, pero tengo un problema con mobile, cuando doy click en el boton desde mi dispositivo mobil la barra superior no aparece
la pagina es la siguiente
http://cosmoscreativeagency.com/alanic/index.html

funcionalidad:

- en dispositivo > 1080px: la linea blanca aparece clickando en el boton de busqueda
- en dispositivo <= 1080px: la barra blanca superior aparecen clickando en el boton de busqueda pero la linea blanca no.

fragmento de codigo abajo:

```js
toggle();
window.onresize = function() {
    toggle();
}
function toggle() {
 var searchTop = document.getElementById('demo-1'); 
 if (window.innerWidth <= 1080) {
  
  document.getElementById('demo-2').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
      alert ("haciendo click");
      document.getElementById('demo-1').style.top = '0px';
  }, true);

  document.getElementById('demo-3').addEventListener('blur', function(evt) {
            document.getElementById('demo-1').style.top = '-60px';
  }, true);

 } else if (window.innerWidth > 1080) {
  document.getElementById('demo-1').style.display = 'none';
 }

}
```

```css
body {
background-color: black;
}
#demo-1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 300;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  top: -60px; }
#demo-1 input[type="search"] {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  color: #000000;
  border: none;
  opacity: 0.9;}
.subheader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  width: 100%; }
#demo-2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 50px;
  float: right;
  z-index: 300; }
#demo-2 input[type="search"] {
  background: url(http://localhost/alanic/images/searchbutton.png) no-repeat 9px center;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.5s; }
#demo-2 input[type="search"]:hover {
  background-color: none; }
#demo-2 input[type="search"]:focus {
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  background-color: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: auto; }
@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
 #demo-2 input[type="search"]:focus {
    display: none; } }
 #demo-2 input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent; }
 #demo-2 input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent; }
 #demo-2 input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff; }
```

```html
<form id="demo-1">
  <input id="demo-3" type="search" name="buscar" placeholder="Search">
</form>   
<div class="subheader">
  <form id="demo-2">
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Emulando un móvil, incluso en una pantalla 240 x 320, funciona correctamente. No creo que sea algún problema de compatibilidad ya que `window#innerWidth` tiene gran soporte de navegadores móviles. ¿Puedes hacer un `alert` en el evento click del search para ver si se muestra en el móvil?

Comment: ok dejeme ver si lo logro hacer el alert para probar si funciona

Comment: hice el alert y no aparece alert en mobile pero si en desktop

Comment: Entonces al parecer no se está ejecutando la función `toggle` en móvil. Imprime cualquier cosa al inicio de la función y al final, con el fin de saber si hay algún error en el código.

Comment: en mobile me da el siguiente error en la consola: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at toggle (blends.js:61)
    at window.onresize (blends.js:54)
toggle @ blends.js:61
window.onresize @ blends.js:54

Comment: ¿de casualidad te aseguraste de ejecutar toggle cuando el documento haya sido renderizado? Es posible que por problemas de latencia se ejecute cuando aún el documento está cargándose.

Comment: quieres decir toggle.onload?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51561/discussion-between-guzgarcia-and-kenny-amaro).